# AsseticBundle / CompassFilter: Any way to throw an exception when a template can't compile?

Tags: symfony, assetic

I'm wondering if anyone can help me with some AsseticBundle configuration in conjunction with Symfony 2's `dev` environment.

Each time a page loads in the `dev` environment Assetic will recompile any assets, in my case I am compiling Sass files using the `CompassFilter`.

My problem is that when I have a malformed Sass file my page simply loads without any generated stylesheet - instead I want Assetic to show me the Compass/Sass compiler output as if an exception had occurred (i.e. I get the Symfony2 "oops" screen).

Does anyone know if there is a configuration to achieve this?

My current `config.yml` is:

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    sass: /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/sass
    filters:
        compass:
          bin: /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/compass
          apply_to: "\.scss$"
        scss: ~
```

with `config_dev.yml` overriding only one line to:

```
assetic:
    use_controller: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, what you ask for is not supported because the stylesheet is processed when it is requested, not when the HTML is requested. However, you should be able to see the error if you request the referenced stylesheet directly.

Comment: That's lucky, an answer from the man himself! Ok, I think I follow with regards to why it can't be shown on page, and also what you've said is true the error actually does come out in the stylesheet but (there had to be a but ;)), while it does contain the stack trace (spawning `CompassFilter` line: 278) it doesn't actually contain the process output (although the code seems to suggest it should). Any idea if it works in the standard case? I could open another question with specifics (stack trace output etc) since this one is technically answered as "not possible" or make an issue on github.

Comment: Sure, open a ticket on Github if you think the exception is unfounded.